# Django : 1048, "Column 'category_id' cannot be null"

Tags: django

This is my code:

```
if ItemSubcategory.objects.filter(name = page_item['slottype']).count() is 0:
    sub_category_set = ItemSubcategory(name = page_item['slottype'])
    sub_category_set.save()
else:
    sub_category_set = ItemSubcategory.objects.get(name = page_item['slottype'])

ni.sub_category = sub_category_set
```

I wonder why it doesn't allow the newly-made object to be fetched and bound. Besides that, the fact that the object returns null (`None`) is odd. I should be able to call it instantly after saving it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with your *‘ItemSubcategory’* model in that when you create an instance of it… you don't supply a *‘category’* for it, only a *‘name’*. When *‘category’* is required. You will need to either supply a *‘category’* or make it so that this field can accept **[null](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)** values.

Another thing worth mentioning is that your code isn't very “**[Pythonic](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html)**” – it took me a minute to work out what exactly your code was doing, when it could be as simple as:

```
# ‘sub_category’ is the model instance
# ‘created’ is True if the object was created and False if it was retrieved
sub_category, created = ItemSubcategory.objects.get_or_create(name = page_item['slottype'])

ni.sub_category = sub_category
ni.save()
```